# Почему нельзя инициализировать переменную результатом вызова функции в си?

Tags: c

Насколько я понял в Си не работает динамическая инициализация для переменных со статической продолжительностью хранению, как в С++.
То есть я не могу сделать вот так:

```
int one()
{ return 1; }

int a = one();

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

MSVC ругается на то, что я должен инициализировать переменную `a`, константой.

И ради интереса я решил сделать так:

```
const int one()
{ return 1; }
```

Тут если я все правильно понял функция вернет не просто `(int)1`, а `(const int)1`. Но и это тоже не работает. Из этого я и делаю вывод: "В Си не работает динамическая инициализация для переменных со статической продолжительностью хранению", или все таки этому явлению есть другое объяснение?

Comment: Значения для глобальных переменных должны быть записаны в исполнимый файл в момент компиляции. А в момент компиляции функции вызываться не могут

Comment: Такой фокус можно делать с статическими переменными класса.

Comment: @nick_n_a, но в си же нет классов

Comment: В c++ для этого есть consexpr

Comment: @КириллМалышев, в с++ я могу сделать это и без constexpr, в отличии от Си

Comment: В плюсах это есть, но с неопределённым порядком инициализации переменных из разных файлов. В Си это делается вручную, и с конкретным порядком. Гарантию даёт стандарт, что все эти переменные сначала нули. *( если не заданы сначала)*

Comment: А какой сложности функция, как вариант... через `#define f(x) ` это можно разрешить? Это будет правда уже несовсем функция... но как вариант.

Comment: В библиотеке pthread например инициализируется макросом структура. `pthread_mutex_t result = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` она всего-лишь задаёт константные значения полям.

Comment: В Си статический объект может быть инициализирован либо строковым литералом, либо константным выражением (_constant expressions_), n1570, 6.7.9/4: `All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.` А константное выражение не может содержать вызовов функций, n1570, 6.6/3: `Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.`

Answer (score 2):

Читаем стандарт

> **5.1.2 Execution environments**
>
> Two execution environments are defined: freestanding and hosted. In
> both cases, program startup occurs when a designated C function is
> called by the execution environment. All objects with static storage
> duration shall be initialized (set to their initial values) **before**
> program startup. The manner and timing of such initialization are
> otherwise unspecified. Program termination returns control to the
> execution environment.

> **5.1.2 Среда выполнения**
>
> Определены две среды выполнения: автономная и помещенная. В обоих
> случаях запуск программы происходит, когда назначенная функция C
> вызывается средой выполнения. Все объекты со статической продолжительностью
> хранения должны быть инициализированы (установлены на их начальные
> значения) **перед** запуском программы. В других случаях способ и время такой
> инициализации не указаны. Завершение программы возвращает управление
> среде выполнения.

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
>
> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or
> thread storage duration shall be **constant** expressions or string
> literals.

> **6.7.9 Инициализация**
>
> Все выражения в инициализаторе для объекта, который имеет статическую
> длительность хранения или поточную, должны быть **константными**
> выражениями или строковыми литералами.

То-есть данные должны быть установлены компилятором **перед** запуском программы. И быть константами. *То есть **не** вычисляться напрямую.*

Comment: "program startup occurs when a designated C function is called" — т.е. тут "запуск программы" есть вызов `main` или схожей функции. Это не объясняет, почему нельзя вызвать `one` до вызова `main`. Комментарий @wololo объясняет.

Answer (score 0):

1. Как уже говорилось, у вас "a" является глобальной переменной. А глобальные переменные инициализируются до этапа выполнения программы.
2. Чтобы получить результат из функции "one()", ее надо выполнить, а как вы собрались это сделать, если эта строчка даже не выполнится? Процессор выполняет функции, а чтобы начать выполнять функцию нужно использовать стек, сохранить текущие состояние программы перед переходом, сделать переход и т.д. Всего этого у вас нет.

"Строительными блоками" в языке Си все же являются функции, а точнее, их тела, выполняемые процессором, в то время, как переменные просто копируются в память.

Answer (score -3):

```
/*
Только так. Функция не может возвращать то чего у неё нет.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
float matematika(float a,float b);
float matematika(float a,float b)
{
static float d=3.14;
float c=a+b;
c*=d
return c;
}
int main(void)
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
float x,y;
//float z=matematika(x,y);// Так не работает.
    printf("Ввод 2-х чисел с плавающей точкой\n");
scanf (" %f %f",&x,&y);
float z=matematika(x,y);//Только так.
    printf("Ответ:%.2f\n",z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какое отношение этот ответ имеет к вопросу?

Comment: Если возвращаемое значение функции не является результатом её вызова тогда никакого. Я только учусь.